# Twig - passing a parameter to a function with a dynamic variable name

Tags: symfony, twig

I have Twig variables:

```
{{ totalAmountMonth0 }} ... {{ totalAmountMonth10 }}
```

I have a loop and I want to call this variable for example:

```
{{ totalAmountMonth5 }}
```

I want to give this variable to a function like this:

```
totalAmount.percentFromTotalAmount((totalAmountMonth5))
```

But this doesn't work:

```
{% for i in 0..10 %}
    {{ totalAmount.percentFromTotalAmount(totalAmountMonth~i) }}
{% endfor %}
```

This doesn't work either:

```
{% for i in 0..10 %}
    {{ totalAmount.percentFromTotalAmount('totalAmountMonth'~i) }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Don't use variable variable names, use an array. E.g. `{% for totalAmountMonth in totalAmountMonthList %}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Untested, but try this:

```
{% for i in 0..10 %}
  {{ totalAmount.percentFromTotalAmount(attribute(_context, 'totalAmountMonth'~i)) }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Just in case someone doesn't know that the special `_context` variable is a global twig variable that contains all currently defined variables as `key => value`, have a look here:  http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/templates.html#global-variables

Answer (score 2):

Just provide to your twig an array, which I suggest, or build it (see below example)

```
// use line below only if array isn't provided to twig
{% set totalAmounts = { totalAmount1, totalAmount2, ..., totalAmount10 } %} // pseudo-code; you need to declare all variables here
{% for ta in totalAmounts %}
    {{ totalAmount.percentFromTotalAmount(ta) }}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to set that variable before and use it.

```
{% for i in 0..10 %}
   {% set temp = 'totalAmountMonth'~i %}
   {{ totalAmount.percentFromTotalAmount(temp) }}
{% endfor %}
```